# Run actions on file changes for linux/mac?

Tags: linux, macos, compilation, devops

I know there are file watchers built into nearly every programming language but from my experience they are either buggy, thus hang and stop reacting to file changes, or resources-greedy.

Now I am working on a project in the Go language (though the tool I am looking for is more likely language-agnostic) and want to run some actions when files are changed and saved.

The only thing I need is a bit of software which watches incoming changes to files (with a certain extension) and performs an action.

Are there any ready to use binaries for Mac OS X/Linux that I can just install with brew or apt-get, and start working?

Please advise!

Answer (score 0):

For Linux you could use the "[inotify tools](https://github.com/rvoicilas/inotify-tools/wiki)":

```
inotifywait -e close_write,moved_to,create  . |
while read -r directory events filename; do
  if [ "$filename" = "myfile.py" ]; then
    ./myfile.py
  fi
done
```